# cast special characters to latin alphabet characters only

Tags: c++, unicode, transliteration

I have to implement a function, which receives an std::string and returns an std::string only consisting of the letters `a-z`:

```
std::string Convert(const std:string& strWithSpecialChars);
```

For example this test should pass:

```
"kilicdaroglu" == Convert("Kılıçdaroğlu");
```

I am not exactly sure if my Point of view is correct, e.g. that `ğ` can be considered as a special form for `g`. I have to support not only turkish letters, but also French letters including accent or German special letters such as `ÄÖÜäöü`.

Background is a validation for the German social security number which includes the first letter of the family name - only `a-z` and I want to validate vs the family name.

Comment: If you don't convert `ğ` to `g`, what would you convert it to?

Comment: Other than having a 'map' of what all potential special characters should be converted to, I don't think the way the Unicode system works allows an easy option for this.

Comment: For example, does `æ` map to `a` or `e`?

Comment: _"German social security number"_ Well, then you'll need to find out how the officialities, who hand out these numbers, do that mapping actually. That should be publicly documented somewhere.

Comment: For extra fun: [which normal form is your input data and what normal form do you intend to produce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985888/when-to-use-unicode-normalization-forms-nfc-and-nfd)

Comment: This feels like an XY-Problem.  Why are you trying to do this?  The proposed conversion results in information loss that you can never recover and may map 2 originally different strings onto the same output string.  What does `ß` map to ?

Comment: Pretty sure not all of those chars are representable as `char`, so you'll already have to use a different kind of string literal/`std::basic_string` instanciation as input. (`L'ç'` has value 231 for me so this is larger than the char max used by my compiler (127).) And I don't think the standard library contains a "looks similar" functionality for characters; you'll probably need to implement the mapping yourself...

Comment: Related: [How to remove accents and tilde in a C++ std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/144761/10871073)

Comment: This is an interesting problem.  French `ï` should become `i`.  But German `ï` should become `ie`.  French `æ` should become `ae`.  German `ß` should become `ss`.  Turkish `ı` or `İ` should become `i`.  Is there something that indicates if the word being converted is French, German, or Turkish?

Comment: Note: you are describing some Latin characters. Accented characters are considered Latin scripts. So probably you googled wrongly. Search for e.g. how to remove accents from a string, etc.)